# ListView hidden value from jsonArray

Tags: android, arrays, listview

my code is this

```
JSONArray jsonArray  = jObj.getJSONArray("subject");
System.out.println(jsonArray.length());
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = jsonObject,getString("idSubject");
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    arrayList.add(name);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, arrayList);
ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.subjectListView);
mylist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I want to know if it's possible to associate to each listView item an hidden value (the id value from the jsonArray) and get it when you call the OnItemClickListener of the listView.
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want hidden elements, then you need to replace android.R.layout.simple... With your own layout. You'll also need an adapter of custom objects, not just strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your hidden value as tag during view rendering.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, arrayList){
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view= super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
       String id = jsonObject,getString("idSubject");
                    view.setTag(id);
                }
            };
```

And during `onItemSelected`

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

       String id=(String)view.getTag()
}
```

Cast this id to original type(string, integer or anything else)

Comment: by position, the list that is passed in adapter and json array both have same indexing.

Comment: add `final` before `JSONArray jsonArray  = jObj.getJSONArray("subject");`

Comment: and i have updated answer too (changed i to position)

Comment: I just explained the idea, exact solution would be to create an independent subclass of `ArrayAdapter` instead of `Anonymous implementation` and pass jsonArray in the constructor. Can you explain what is not clean @lelloman

Comment: I didn't, btw please justify what is not clean that would better help others